# Should <link ref="dns-prefetch"> tag be placed as high as possible in <head> website?

Tags: html, web, dns, prefetch

I'm implementing the new `dns-prefetch` tag for my web application and I wonder where I should place it in the `<head>` tag?

Should I place it as the first tag in `<head>` so that browser immediately starts prefetching DNS?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//ajax.googleapis.com">
  ... other tags ...
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

I can't find a good guide about this tag.

Comment: I think the reason this doesnt have a canonical answer yet is because Android and iOS don't yet support it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-dns-prefetch. Until that happens its going to be hard to do the real world tests to effectively answer how positioning this tag affects latency on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive rule as to the placement of the tag, however the best practice is, as you suggest, to place it as early as possible on the head, right after any existing meta charset tag.[1][2]

That been said, the example provided may not be the best use of dns-prefetch given that you will (likely) shortly after load your ajax modules which will end up being an extra line with no change in performance.[3]

[1]http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/how-your-browser-speeds-up-cross-domain-loading-using-dns-prefetching.html

[2]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Controlling_DNS_prefetching

[3]https://jack.ofspades.com/prefetching-preloading-and-prerendering-content-with-html/

Comment: I had a more elaborate setup in mind, let's say a '<link rel...' for a CSS which in turn references a foreign domain for web font download + a DNS prefetch for that domain. I was concerned that if `<head>` childs are processed sequentially (even with parallel HTTP downloads) DNS prefetch after the CSS reference may be processed too late. After thinking it through, however, any reasonable implementation of parallelism will just queue the HTTP resource downloads and thus the order of DNS prefetch elements likely has no practical consequence.